# How to retrieve a commit from git

Tags: sql, git

I am trying to get a **_**.sql files from previous commits

I tried

```
git show <commit> > exporthere.sql
```

but it doesn't give me original sql files but with all the characters that I don't need.

I also tried

```
git archive -o exporthere.sql/txt <commit>
```

but it doesn't open for some reason.

What can I do to get the original sql file that I/team committed?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply do:

```
$ git show branch:path/to/sql.file
```

to get the latest version on the branch called **branch** ? If not, have you seen the [examples towards the end of the git show man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html), which cover a multitude of options ?

Comment: yes I have already tried git show and all it does is just mess up the original code by adding bunch of characters in the front. I want the original code that I committed

Comment: I don't want the author name, date or anything but just purely my code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
  git show HEAD^:exporthere.sql
```

`HEAD^` refers to the previous commit, `exporthere.sql` is the file you want to display. (Add Path if it is not in the root directory of your repository.)
Instead of `HEAD^` you can refer to any other commit, e.g. some SHA1.

It should print out the file exactly as is was commited, without author or any additional characters.

Alternatively you can first checkout the old revision with `git checkout HEAD^`.
Now you have the complete repository at the state of the previous commit.

You can get back to the current version of your repository with `git checkout master`. (Assuming `master` is your current branch.)

Comment: no need to say "thank you". just upvote and accept the answer. ;)